# Prove that if $g_i(\hat{x})>0$ for all $i$, then $\{x:\lVert x-\hat{x}\rVert<\epsilon \}\subset S$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, proof-writing

I'm working on this question for my Optimization Theory class:

Let $S=\{x:g_i(x)\ge0,  i=1,\ldots,m\}$ and assume that the functions $\{g_i\}$ are continuous. Prove that if $g_i(\hat{x})>0$ for all $i$, then $\{x:\lVert x-\hat{x}\rVert<\epsilon \}\subset S$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

Specifically, I'm not sure I'm interpreting some of the symbols correctly. First, I recall from my calculus 3 class that $\hat{x}$ represents a unit vector. Second, I recognize $\lVert x\rVert$ represents the magnitude of a vector. Am I being asked to show that if $g_i$ evaluated at the unit-vector is non-negative then the magnitude of $x-\hat{x}<\epsilon$? Or does this symbol represent something completely different in this context?

Comment: No, $\hat{x}$ isn't a unit vector.  It's simply some particular point which is strictly feasible.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: For example,  "Prove that if $g_i(\hat{x})>0$ for all $i$, then $\{x:\lVert x-\hat{x}\rVert<\epsilon \}\subset S$" is a better choice

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I thought you were looking for a solution.

> Let, $U_i:=g_i^{-1}(B(g_i(\hat{x}), g_i(\hat{x})/2))$, where $B(g_i(\hat{x}), g_i(\hat{x})/2)$ is the open ball of radius $g_i(\hat{x})/2$ centered at $g_i(\hat{x})$. As $g_i$ is continuous $U_i$ is open, and by definition $g_i(x)>0$ for all $x$ in $U_i$, so $U_i\subseteq S$. Now $U:=U_1 \cap\cdots\cap U_m$ is an open subset of $S$, and $\hat{x}\in U$, thus for some $\epsilon>0$, $B(\hat{x},\epsilon)\subseteq U\subseteq S$.